# Gibraltar date formatting: expected GB-like format while got US-like one

Tags: java, locale, date-formatting

With Joda:

```java
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GI"); // Gibraltar
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.shortDate().withLocale(locale);
DateTime date = new DateTime(2019, 6, 20, 9, 30); // 20 June 2019
String formatted = date.toString(formatter);
```

With Java8:

```java
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "GI"); // Gibraltar
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT).withLocale(locale);
LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.of(2019, 6, 20, 9, 30); // 20 June 2019
String formatted = formatter.format(date);
```

In both cases, `formatted` is equal to `6/20/19` while I was expecting `20/06/19`, given that Wikipedia states that [the Gibraltarian date format is dd/mm/yyyy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar?oldformat=true).

Any idea of a fix (different from "if GI then GB")?

Note: when you use `new Locale("en", "GB")`, you do get the expected result.

Comment: Fixed in Java 9+

Comment: @Andreas is right: while I can reproduce your result on Java 8 (1.8.0_121), on Java 9 (9.0.4) I get the `20/06/2019` that you say you would have wanted (tested with java.time).

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for having checked with Java9, something I should have done before asking actually. Well, I'll hack around until we migrate our codebase to Java9+ then, thanks! Poor Gibraltarians though...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's fixed in a later version of Java.